# How to show the contents of view page from template?

Tags: views, theming

I'm trying to theme a view page on Drupal 7, I used views-view--name-of-page.tpl.php

So now it's blank right? I invoked some blocks on the view page and added some divs to style but I can't seem to show the contents of the view page.

I have tried

```
print render ($content);   
print $content; 
print $page;
```

etc.

Like what we do for node. but it's not working on views template.

Can anyone suggest me?

Comment: I suggest to compare it to the regular `page.tpl.php` file and see what are you missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this type of template file you can not use 
print render ($content);   
print $content; 
print $page;

Instead of you can use 
In **page template** file you can only use **$rows** variable for display output.
print $rows; for display result.

Answer (score 0):

In view Advanced Section  `Theming information` click `Rescan template Files` for your theme.

Answer (score 0):

In the Views-> Advanced -> Other -> Theme: Information -> You need to rescan template files.

Then in your tpl

```
foreach ($view->style_plugin->rendered_fields as $key => $value) {

print_r($value);

}
```

$value will render the required values.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `$content` nor `$page` won't work for Views templates, these variables initialized by other theme system functions (for ex. `template_preprocess_page`); Views provides own (different) variables, you can find them [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme%21theme.inc/7). If you want to see what variables are available for you to use, you can open `Advanced - Theme:Information - Display output` and look at its comments..